# How to use javascript epoch time directly in google charts?

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

```
    google.load('visualization', '1', {
    packages: ['corechart', 'line']
});
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawBasic);

function drawBasic() {

    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    data.addColumn('number', 'X');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Current Data');

    data.addRows([
        [
        1413154800000,
        0],
        [
        1413158400000,
        0],
        [
        1413162000000,
        0],
        [
        1413165600000,
        0],
        [
        1413169200000,
        0],
        [
        1413172800000,
        0],
        [
        1413176400000,
        0],
        [
        1413180000000,
        1],
        [
        1413183600000,
        5],
        [
        1413187200000,
        20],
        [
        1413190800000,
        16],
        [
        1413194400000,
        8],
        [
        1413198000000,
        2],
        [
        1413201600000,
        3],
        [
        1413205200000,
        2],
        [
        1413208800000,
        0],
        [
        1413212400000,
        0],
        [
        1413216000000,
        0],
        [
        1413219600000,
        0],
        [
        1413223200000,
        0],
        [
        1413226800000,
        0],
        [
        1413230400000,
        0],
        [
        1413234000000,
        0],
        [
        1413237600000,
        0]
    ]);

    var options = {
        hAxis: {
            title: 'Current Time',
            gridlines: {
                color: 'none'
            }
        },
        vAxis: {
            title: 'Minutes',
            gridlines: {
                color: 'none'
            }
        },
        curveType: 'function'
    };

    var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));

    chart.draw(data, options);
}
```

For creating a line chart, the data set is in epoch values. if its passed with new Date(epoch_value)  like **[ new Date(1413230400000),   0]**, it throws an error. Also tried setting type as date in options, which also doesn't work.

Basically I want it to be in date / time format.

[image: desired chart]

Fiddle link :
[link](https://jsfiddle.net/sedhuait/oaomr4mg/)

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `DateFormatter`

Docs:
https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#dateformat

Your fixed:
https://jsfiddle.net/phpowl/fun24h3q/1/

Comment: hey thanks it works perfectly. I have doubt. My data is will be huge one. Previously I was using highcharts, it takes epoch times directly. But in case of google charts. if this is the only way, then I need to iterate through all the values to make use of the date formatter. Is there any better way???

Comment: I think the better way is prepare these two values in a backend part if it's possible.